# will my kitten have short hair or medium hair?

Tags: cats

[image]

how long will her hair be? she is extremely fluffy and thick haired and she had pretty long ear hair[image][image][image][image]

Comment: your cat has long hair and this is not likely to change.

Comment: The long hairs in this picture look like guard hairs (aka fuzzies) that all young kittens have.